# Is it possible to extent the existing RTF item (hyperlink) in web 8?

Tags: cme

I am trying to extend the existing RTF item (Hyperlink) and wanted to add another attribute which should reflect in anchor source as a new attribute.

For now, the hyperlink showing 4 fields (type,URL,title,target) in the overlay. when i fill these fields it reflect in the RTF source as an anchor tag. for example "google.com"

i wanted to extent this feature to add one more attribute "ID" (like title,href) in the anchor source. I also want to add another field in hyperlink (apart from above 4 mentioned fields) that called as "ID" with a text box which help me to input the ID value and when i click OK then it should bind that ID to the anchor source along with another attributes. I am using SDL web 8.

Comment: Please check here. https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/883/unable-to-preserve-custom-attributes-in-rtf-fields

Comment: Hi Rajesh, Thank for this. But i also want a input field in hyperlink (overlay) which input the ID and push that into RTF source. Do you have any clue about that?

Comment: Try looking into GUI Extension.